# Insert Values In SQLITE Database

Tags: iphone, ios, database, ios5, sqlite

I tried to insert values in sqlite3 database, but it cant work on my app.
I follow this code where all this values in table are varchar.

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
int ID;
// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

// Build the path to the database file
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"weather.sqlite"]];


const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO satish VALUES ('jodhpur','hazy1','68','7','700','30','28','10sept')"];

    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",statement);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, insert_stmt, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT );

        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            ID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(contactDB);

            NSLog(@"Data inserted successfully ");

        } 
        else{             
            NSLog(@"Failed to add contact");
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//tyr this code    
// you must give the column name to insert values in DB   

     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

            NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            NSError *error;
            NSString *dbPath =[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"register.sqlite"];
            BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath]; 
            sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
            if(!success)
            {
                NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"register.sqlite"];
                success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

                if (!success) 
                    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
            }

            if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
                //*************** insert value in database******************************\\ 

                const char *sql = "insert into satish (firstname,lastname,email,company,phone) VALUES ('sdcbb','bbbb','bbbb','bbbb',1111122)";
                sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL); 
                if(sqlite3_step(selectstmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    NSLog(@"insert successfully");
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"insert not successfully");

                }
            sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
                sqlite3_close(database);
            }
```

Comment: sorry,i am not changed DB name, register.sqlite is my DB name

Comment: you change register.sqlite to weather.sqlite

Comment: and change "insert into satish (your column names) VALUES (your values)";

Comment: in your code ,it give some error near database ,says use to undeclared identifier 'datadase'

Comment: add "static sqlite3 *database = nil; " in after "@implementation class name"

Comment: when i run this code then its work fine and show insert successfully but when i open my database then not showing inserted values.what is that problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16761/discussion-between-shashi-sharma-and-nannav)

Comment: check 
library->application support->iphone simulator->versin of simulator->application->find your app folder ->document->weather.sqllite

Comment: hey i am using xcode 4.4, and in which no iphone simulator folder in application support.

Comment: their is no such folder in it

Comment: i copy my database into my app and run on sqlite3 manager,this is show no such entry into table satish.

Comment: it is my folder path " /Users/leorajasekaran/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.0.2/Applications/2FBD4EF4-E047-4873-A48D-547CB9764FAF/Documents"

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you copy your database from your bundle to the documents directory.  If you do not copy a premade SQLite database, then your open call will create a new empty one.  Since you did not create a table yet in your empty database, then the Insert call will fail.  Solution 1:  Write file routines to copy a premade SQLite database with a table named satish into your documents directory.  Solution 2:  If you don't want to premake a sqlite database, use a create statement in SQLite first to create the satish table.